# How to multiply in C++

Tags: c++

SO basically I am stuck on this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "please enter your first name and age\n"; //prompts user to enter name and age
    string first_name; //string variable
    int age; //integer variable
    cin first_name; //reads first_name
    cin age; //reads age
    cout << "Hello " << first_name << " (age" << age << ")\n"; 
}
```

Hi, I just started c++ two days ago, and I would like help. I want to multiply the int age by 12, where abouts do I do it like this?

```
cin age*12
```

or do I put it here

```
int age*12
```

Again, sorry that it's a newb question, but I just started two days ago. I'm not even sure if there are errors in it, but I only need that part answered.

Comment: You can't multiply until you've read a value, so you can't multiply until after the `cin age` has executed.

Comment: I wouldn't put it either place. I would put it on the cout line: cout ... << " (age" << (age * 12) << ....;

Comment: _`cin age; //reads age`_ it doesn't. You'll need something like `cin >> age; //reads age` instead.

Comment: *I'm not even sure if there are errors in it* - There's your main problem. Any compiler will complain and tell you there are.

Comment: @chris Just to fortify your comment: http://ideone.com/0HN9Cl

Comment: I did what murion said and it worked out.#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"
int main() {
 cout << "Please enter your first name and age\n";
 string first_name;
 int age;
 cin >> first_name;
 cin >> age; 
 cout << "Hello " << first_name << " (age in months = " << age * 12 << ")\n";
 system("pause");
}

Comment: @KurokoTomoko _"I did what murion said and it worked out"_ You still have compiler errors, nothing works. Fix the basics (not in your question samples).

Answer (score 3):

Your program should be like this:

```
int main() {
   cout << "please enter your first name and age\n"; //prompts user to enter name and age
   string first_name; //string variable
   int age; //integer variable
   cin >> first_name; //reads first_name
   cin >> age; //reads age

   int result = age * 12;
   cout << "Hello " << first_name << " (age" << age << ")\n"; 
   cout << "Your age multiplied by 12 is " << result << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a new int called `int agetwo`, then do `agetwo = age*12` and print out `agetwo`.

So basically,

```
int agetwo=age*12;
cout << agetwo;
```

as other have said, can then also do

`cout << age*12`

just a style preference for which one you use.

Comment: int main() {
cout << "please enter your first name and age\n"; //prompts user to enter name and age
string first_name; //string variable
int age; //integer variable
cin first_name; //reads first_name
cin age; //reads age
cout << "Hello " << first_name << " (age" << age * 12 << ")\n";  So I added age * 12 in the cout would that work?

Comment: @KurokoTomoko yes that could work but its always better to put it in a variable for if you would ever want to change anything in the program later.

Comment: @jgr208 Could be done inline with the `std::cout` expression statement as well, no need for a variable actually.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes i know just my style I guess you can say.  To make a more readable for the next person, but nothing wrong with that as well.

Comment: @KurokoTomoko if you would like to accept it then please select the pick answer check mark, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to output the value of `age * 12` then you can say:

```
std::cout << age * 12;
```

If you want to store the value of `age * 12` then you can say:

```
age = age * 12;
```

Comment: Or   age *= 12.     The OP really needs to obtain and READ a basic text.   This sort of thing is covered quite early.

Comment: Yeah thats what IM using. . . but he didn't cover that part. . .

Comment: A good coding standard is to place the multiplication inside parenthesis when using the stream insertion operators:  `std::cout << (age * 12);`.  This forces the multiplication to be performed first.